# SQLcl Error in java : package oracle.jdbc.internal is sealed

Tags: oracle, sqlcl

I am not able to access (get/retrieve) any data from Database. 
I see this error every time when I need to work in SQLcl and, I was not able to find any solution in Oracle Community

[image]

Comment: You can find your answer in this [thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4167743)

Comment: finally i find solution  , if any body get this error you can copy jar file ojdbc8  from sqlcl/lib/ojdbc8.jar
and put this jar file 
 JDBC  Folder  you can find  it in Database Folders